# How to align text view in android list view?

Tags: android, android-layout, android-listview, android-xml

My list view looks like that and its very bad because if name is longer than surname text view goes over my date and prefix A which means arrival, but if surname longer than name everything is ok. 
However i am here to ask maybe someone knows how to align them that text views wont go over each other?
[image]
this is my xml of single row item:

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
 <RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
          android:layout_width="fill_parent"
          android:layout_height="fill_parent"
          android:orientation="vertical">

<TextView android:id="@+id/name"
          android:layout_width="wrap_content"
          android:layout_height="wrap_content"
          android:text="Sample Data"
          android:textSize="15sp"
          android:paddingBottom="5dp" />

<TextView android:id="@+id/surName"
          android:layout_width="wrap_content"
          android:layout_height="wrap_content"
          android:text="Sample Data 2"
          android:textSize="15sp"
          android:layout_below="@id/name"
          android:paddingBottom="5dp" />

  <TextView
      android:id="@+id/textA"
      android:layout_width="wrap_content"
      android:layout_height="wrap_content"
      android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/surName"
      android:paddingBottom="5dp"
      android:paddingLeft="10dp"
      android:paddingRight="5dp"
      android:text="A:"
      android:textSize="15sp" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/date"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:paddingBottom="5dp"
    android:paddingLeft="5dp"
    android:paddingRight="5dp"
    android:layout_toRightOf="@id/textA"
    android:text="Sample Data 3"
    android:textSize="15sp" />
 <TextView
      android:id="@+id/time"
      android:layout_width="wrap_content"
      android:layout_height="wrap_content"
      android:layout_alignBaseline="@+id/surName"
      android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/surName"
      android:layout_alignLeft="@id/date"
      android:paddingBottom="5dp"
      android:paddingLeft="5dp"
      android:paddingRight="5dp"
      android:text="Sample Data 4"
      android:textSize="15sp" />
<TextView
      android:id="@+id/textD"
      android:layout_width="wrap_content"
      android:layout_height="wrap_content"
      android:layout_toRightOf="@id/date"
      android:paddingBottom="5dp"
      android:paddingLeft="5dp"
      android:paddingRight="5dp"
      android:text="D:"
      android:textSize="15sp" />
 <TextView
    android:id="@+id/date2"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:paddingBottom="5dp"
    android:paddingLeft="5dp"
    android:paddingRight="5dp"
    android:layout_toRightOf="@id/textD"
    android:text="Sample Data 3"
    android:textSize="15sp" />
 <TextView
      android:id="@+id/time2"
      android:layout_width="wrap_content"
      android:layout_height="wrap_content"
      android:layout_below="@id/date2"
      android:layout_alignBottom="@id/time"
      android:layout_alignLeft="@id/date2"
      android:paddingBottom="5dp"
      android:paddingLeft="5dp"
      android:paddingRight="5dp"
      android:text="Sample Data 4"
      android:textSize="15sp" />



  </RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: Use linear layout with weightsum

Comment: tried this one, weightsum not allowing me to make 2 rows in one row like did now, and everythings goes into disorder.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
          android:layout_width="fill_parent"
          android:layout_height="fill_parent"
          android:orientation="vertical">
<LinearLayout 
 android:id="@+id/namesur"
 android:layout_width="wrap_content"
 android:layout_height="wrap_content"
 android:orientation="vertical"
 >
<TextView android:id="@+id/name"
          android:layout_width="wrap_content"
          android:layout_height="wrap_content"
          android:text="Sample Data"
            android:layout_weight="1"
          android:textSize="15sp"
          android:paddingBottom="5dp" />

<TextView android:id="@+id/surName"
          android:layout_width="wrap_content"
          android:layout_height="wrap_content"
          android:text="Sample Data 2"
          android:layout_weight="1"
          android:textSize="15sp"
          android:layout_below="@id/name"
          android:paddingBottom="5dp" />
</LinearLayout>
  <TextView
      android:id="@+id/textA"
      android:layout_width="wrap_content"
      android:layout_height="wrap_content"
      android:layout_toRightOf="@id/namesur"
      android:paddingBottom="5dp"
      android:paddingLeft="10dp"
      android:paddingRight="5dp"
      android:text="A:"
      android:textSize="15sp" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/date"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:paddingBottom="5dp"
    android:paddingLeft="5dp"
    android:paddingRight="5dp"
    android:layout_toRightOf="@id/textA"
    android:text="Sample Data 3"
    android:textSize="15sp" />
 <TextView
      android:id="@+id/time"
      android:layout_width="wrap_content"
      android:layout_height="wrap_content"
      android:layout_alignBaseline="@id/namesur"
      android:layout_alignBottom="@id/namesur"
      android:layout_alignLeft="@id/date"
      android:paddingBottom="5dp"
      android:paddingLeft="5dp"
      android:paddingRight="5dp"
      android:text="Sample Data 4"
      android:textSize="15sp" />
<TextView
      android:id="@+id/textD"
      android:layout_width="wrap_content"
      android:layout_height="wrap_content"
      android:layout_toRightOf="@id/date"
      android:paddingBottom="5dp"
      android:paddingLeft="5dp"
      android:paddingRight="5dp"
      android:text="D:"
      android:textSize="15sp" />
 <TextView
    android:id="@+id/date2"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:paddingBottom="5dp"
    android:paddingLeft="5dp"
    android:paddingRight="5dp"
    android:layout_toRightOf="@id/textD"
    android:text="Sample Data 3"
    android:textSize="15sp" />
 <TextView
      android:id="@+id/time2"
      android:layout_width="wrap_content"
      android:layout_height="wrap_content"
      android:layout_below="@id/date2"
      android:layout_alignBottom="@id/time"
      android:layout_alignLeft="@id/date2"
      android:paddingBottom="5dp"
      android:paddingLeft="5dp"
      android:paddingRight="5dp"
      android:text="Sample Data 4"
      android:textSize="15sp" />
```

Answer (score 1):

you are using relative layout so add :

```
android:layout_toLeftOf
android:layout_toRightOf
```

in your textviews so thet they wont go over each other

Comment: no, because of doing that text view gonna align by name and surname and i want them both align in one line like column

Comment: then you have to set your surname text view  align right:"@id/name" and they will be the same lenght

Answer (score 1):

This works perfectly for me::

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:padding="5dp"
    android:orientation="horizontal">

    <TableLayout
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:shrinkColumns="*"
        android:stretchColumns="*"
        android:weightSum="2">

        <TableRow android:weightSum="15"
            android:paddingBottom="5dp">

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/name"
                android:ellipsize="marquee"
                android:maxWidth="120dp"
                android:singleLine="true"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_weight="5"
                android:text="Sample Data"
                android:textSize="15sp" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/textA"
                android:ellipsize="marquee"
                android:singleLine="true"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_weight="2"
                android:text="A:"
                android:textSize="15sp" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/date"
                android:ellipsize="marquee"
                android:maxWidth="90dp"
                android:singleLine="true"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_weight="3"
                android:text="Sample Data 3"
                android:textSize="15sp" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/textD"
                android:ellipsize="marquee"
                android:singleLine="true"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_weight="2"
                android:text="D:"
                android:textSize="15sp" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/date2"
                android:ellipsize="marquee"
                android:maxWidth="90dp"
                android:singleLine="true"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_weight="3"
                android:text="Sample Data 3"
                android:textSize="15sp" />
        </TableRow>

        <TableRow android:weightSum="15"
            android:paddingBottom="5dp">

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/surName"
                android:ellipsize="marquee"
                android:maxWidth="120dp"
                android:singleLine="true"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_weight="5"
                android:text="Sample Data 2"
                android:textSize="15sp" />

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_weight="2"
                android:ellipsize="marquee"
                android:singleLine="true"
                android:text="  "
                android:textSize="15sp" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/time"
                android:ellipsize="marquee"
                android:maxWidth="90dp"
                android:singleLine="true"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_weight="3"
                android:text="Sample Data 4"
                android:textSize="15sp" />

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_weight="2"
                android:ellipsize="marquee"
                android:singleLine="true"
                android:text="  "
                android:textSize="15sp" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/time2"
                android:ellipsize="marquee"
                android:maxWidth="90dp"
                android:singleLine="true"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_weight="3"
                android:text="Sample Data 4"
                android:textSize="15sp" />
        </TableRow>

    </TableLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

I've created a table with two rows, and used `weightSum` to proportion the textviews. Setting `ellipsize="marquee"` and `maxWidth` for ensures that the text doesn't overlap into the next item in the row.